# Will there be armel images for 14.04?

Tags: release-management

Looking at [this page](http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty/main/), it looks like **armel** arch will not be provided for 14.04. I'd that the case? Why so and when did this happen?

As a sidenote, I run **armel** 12.04 on my embedded systems, and haven't checked if armhf works.

Comment: Here the source https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu no longer provides pre-built images of new Ubuntu versions for *armel*. It only provides images for *armhf* (Hard Float, instead of floating-point emulation).

What Single Board Computer (SBC) are you using? The only popular SBC that requires armel is the Raspberry Pi. All other work with armhf.

For the Raspberry Pi, there was an effort to re-build the Ubuntu repositories to support the Raspberry Pi at http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2013/11/building-ubuntu-for-the-raspberry-pi/ Not sure whether the project was successful.

Comment: [VAB-800: Freescale i.MX537 Cortex-A8 SoC](http://www.viaembedded.com/en/products/boards/1930/1/VAB-800_%28Pico-ITX%29.html)

Comment: The SoC (Cortex-A8) supports hard float according to http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-a/cortex-a8.php (see Specifications and mention of VFPv3). However, with such an SBC, you need to check what available images you can get from the manufacturer.